7 year old girl still acting like a toddler
I am having difficulty with the behaviour of my 7 year old daughter. She does not behave appropriately for her age. Examples of her behaviour include:

Unable to toilet train, still in nappies
Problems with sleep - it is very difficult to get her to go to sleep at bedtime
Unreasonable expectations - she cries and screams to get what she wants

I have consulted professionals, mainly about the toilet training, but with no success.
I do not know what the reason is for this behaviour, but they seem similar. Could anyone suggest what might be the best course of action?

Hi there, this question appears to be asking several different things. Typically on the Stack Exchange network questions should focus on one unique, and answerable problem. Based on what I can see here you might find some useful information via the search function, and parsing through previously asked questions. I'd also recommend that talking to a pediatrician or your family practitioner might be a good place to start. Good luck!

In no way is the followin question ment offensive: Does she have any mental issues, maybe a learning disability? Or is it more like being stubborn?

tl;dr
Check for root causes in the following order:
physical issues, psychological issues, social/systemic issues.

At that age (and frankly also at others), the course of action is as follows:

Contact your primary healthcare provider, e.g. your pediatrician. You want to assess where she is with regards to development milestones (you clearly describe that there is some deviation).
If you can go into that consultation with a detailed description of what seems amiss and what you want, you can help them a lot. They will typically assess your child’s physical and mental development and may seek counsel from specialist or some tests to discover physical issues. Hint: When making the appointment, ask (nicely but persistently) for a longer time slot and explain the context a bit - better a later date with sufficient time than an earlier rushed appointment.
If she’s physically fine, get a child psychologist involved. I would expect that in case of a clean bill of health or some questions, you’d get a referral from 1. anyway.
If your child is seemingly fine, but they, you, or you as a family still struggle, look at the surrounding system. Look into what’s happening in the family, school, social circle etc. A therapist or counsellor should be able to help you.

Depending on what you discover in steps 1 - 3, the way to resolve or manage the situation should become clearer.
